# Can't find pocketsphinx gstreamer plugin

Tags: gstreamer, cmusphinx

I tried to install pocketsphinx by

> brew instal cmu-pocketsphinx

and

> make install (followed instructions here: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/gstreamer)

the pocketsphinx_continuous works properly, but I can't find a executable pocketsphinx for

> gst-inspect pocketsphinx

could anyone tell me where to find it, please?

Many many thanks

pocketsphinx install log:  http://pastebin.com/48QU0qjg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if plugin pocketsphinx.so is installed in

```
  /usr/local/lib/gstreamer-<version>
```

If plugin is there you need to export GST_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable to update gstreamer search path.

If plugin is not there you need to check build log for the information why plugin was not created or installed properly. Most likely you didn't have required development headers so plugin compilation was disabled.

Comment: thanks for your reply. There is no pocketsphinx.so in that dir, I checked the log, it's like: libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/_pocketsphinx.0.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx/_pocketsphinx.0.so

Comment: No, this is a python component, it is not gstreamer. You need to check earlier in the log. If you can't check yourself you can always paste your log to pastebin and give a link here or share it some other way.

Comment: According to the log gstreamer plugin is not compiled. You can check file config.log for details.

Comment: that's it, after checked config.log I find out the gst-plugin-base wasn't installed. thank you so much! BTW, care to share how did you find out plugin is not compiled by viewing make_install log?

Comment: This part

`Making install in gst-plugin`
`make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.`
`make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.`
`make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.`

says that there is nothing installed from gst-plugin folder. If plugin was compiled it would be installed somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem under Raspbian Jessie. The problem was that when I compiled Pocketsphinx the libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev was missing, so no plugin could be compiled. I solved by installing the missing package then recompiling Pocketsphinx. Check this for more info https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/speech-recognition/thread/040066c7/

Hope it helps