# gi._glib.GError: no element "pocketsphinx" error on running livedemo

Tags: gstreamer, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am using ubuntu 14.04

I am trying to get a python program to get speech to text from microphone.
For this, I have installed sphinxbase and pocketsphinx. `pocketsphinx_continuous` works.

```
thekindlyone@deepthought:.../lib$ pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes
INFO: cmd_ln.c(691): Parsing command line:
pocketsphinx_continuous \
    -inmic yes 

Current configuration:
[NAME]      [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
-adcdev             
-agc        none        none
-agcthresh  2.0     2.000000e+00
-alpha      0.97        9.700000e-01
-argfile            
-ascale     20.0        2.000000e+01
-aw     1       1
-backtrace  no      no
-beam       1e-48       1.000000e-48
-bestpath   yes     yes
-bestpathlw 9.5     9.500000e+00
-bghist     no      no
-ceplen     13      13
-cmn        current     current
-cmninit    8.0     8.0
-compallsen no      no
-debug              0
-dict               
-dictcase   no      no
-dither     no      no
-doublebw   no      no
-ds     1       1
-fdict              
-feat       1s_c_d_dd   1s_c_d_dd
-featparams         
-fillprob   1e-8        1.000000e-08
-frate      100     100
-fsg                
-fsgusealtpron  yes     yes
-fsgusefiller   yes     yes
-fwdflat    yes     yes
-fwdflatbeam    1e-64       1.000000e-64
-fwdflatefwid   4       4
-fwdflatlw  8.5     8.500000e+00
-fwdflatsfwin   25      25
-fwdflatwbeam   7e-29       7.000000e-29
-fwdtree    yes     yes
-hmm                
-infile             
-input_endian   little      little
-jsgf               
-kdmaxbbi   -1      -1
-kdmaxdepth 0       0
-kdtree             
-latsize    5000        5000
-lda                
-ldadim     0       0
-lextreedump    0       0
-lifter     0       0
-lm             
-lmctl              
-lmname     default     default
-logbase    1.0001      1.000100e+00
-logfn              
-logspec    no      no
-lowerf     133.33334   1.333333e+02
-lpbeam     1e-40       1.000000e-40
-lponlybeam 7e-29       7.000000e-29
-lw     6.5     6.500000e+00
-maxhmmpf   -1      -1
-maxnewoov  20      20
-maxwpf     -1      -1
-mdef               
-mean               
-mfclogdir          
-min_endfr  0       0
-mixw               
-mixwfloor  0.0000001   1.000000e-07
-mllr               
-mmap       yes     yes
-ncep       13      13
-nfft       512     512
-nfilt      40      40
-nwpen      1.0     1.000000e+00
-pbeam      1e-48       1.000000e-48
-pip        1.0     1.000000e+00
-pl_beam    1e-10       1.000000e-10
-pl_pbeam   1e-5        1.000000e-05
-pl_window  0       0
-rawlogdir          
-remove_dc  no      no
-round_filters  yes     yes
-samprate   16000       1.600000e+04
-seed       -1      -1
-sendump            
-senlogdir          
-senmgau            
-silprob    0.005       5.000000e-03
-smoothspec no      no
-svspec             
-time       no      no
-tmat               
-tmatfloor  0.0001      1.000000e-04
-topn       4       4
-topn_beam  0       0
-toprule            
-transform  legacy      legacy
-unit_area  yes     yes
-upperf     6855.4976   6.855498e+03
-usewdphones    no      no
-uw     1.0     1.000000e+00
-var                
-varfloor   0.0001      1.000000e-04
-varnorm    no      no
-verbose    no      no
-warp_params            
-warp_type  inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wbeam      7e-29       7.000000e-29
-wip        0.65        6.500000e-01
-wlen       0.025625    2.562500e-02

INFO: cmd_ln.c(691): Parsing command line:
\
    -nfilt 20 \
    -lowerf 1 \
    -upperf 4000 \
    -wlen 0.025 \
    -transform dct \
    -round_filters no \
    -remove_dc yes \
    -svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38 \
    -feat 1s_c_d_dd \
    -agc none \
    -cmn current \
    -cmninit 56,-3,1 \
    -varnorm no 

Current configuration:
[NAME]      [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
-agc        none        none
-agcthresh  2.0     2.000000e+00
-alpha      0.97        9.700000e-01
-ceplen     13      13
-cmn        current     current
-cmninit    8.0     56,-3,1
-dither     no      no
-doublebw   no      no
-feat       1s_c_d_dd   1s_c_d_dd
-frate      100     100
-input_endian   little      little
-lda                
-ldadim     0       0
-lifter     0       0
-logspec    no      no
-lowerf     133.33334   1.000000e+00
-ncep       13      13
-nfft       512     512
-nfilt      40      20
-remove_dc  no      yes
-round_filters  yes     no
-samprate   16000       1.600000e+04
-seed       -1      -1
-smoothspec no      no
-svspec             0-12/13-25/26-38
-transform  legacy      dct
-unit_area  yes     yes
-upperf     6855.4976   4.000000e+03
-varnorm    no      no
-verbose    no      no
-warp_params            
-warp_type  inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wlen       0.025625    2.500000e-02

INFO: acmod.c(246): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from /usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/feat.params
INFO: feat.c(713): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: cmn.c(142): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
INFO: acmod.c(167): Using subvector specification 0-12/13-25/26-38
INFO: mdef.c(517): Reading model definition: /usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/mdef
INFO: mdef.c(528): Found byte-order mark BMDF, assuming this is a binary mdef file
INFO: bin_mdef.c(336): Reading binary model definition: /usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/mdef
INFO: bin_mdef.c(513): 50 CI-phone, 143047 CD-phone, 3 emitstate/phone, 150 CI-sen, 5150 Sen, 27135 Sen-Seq
INFO: tmat.c(205): Reading HMM transition probability matrices: /usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/transition_matrices
INFO: acmod.c(121): Attempting to use SCHMM computation module
INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1 codebook, 3 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1 codebook, 3 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(354): 0 variance values floored
INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(903): Loading senones from dump file /usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/sendump
INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(927): BEGIN FILE FORMAT DESCRIPTION
INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(1022): Using memory-mapped I/O for senones
INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(1296): Maximum top-N: 4 Top-N beams: 0 0 0
INFO: dict.c(317): Allocating 137543 * 32 bytes (4298 KiB) for word entries
INFO: dict.c(332): Reading main dictionary: /usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/lm/en_US/cmu07a.dic
INFO: dict.c(211): Allocated 1010 KiB for strings, 1664 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(335): 133436 words read
INFO: dict.c(341): Reading filler dictionary: /usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/noisedict
INFO: dict.c(211): Allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(344): 11 words read
INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables for dictionary
INFO: dict2pid.c(404): Allocating 50^3 * 2 bytes (244 KiB) for word-initial triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(131): Allocated 60400 bytes (58 KiB) for word-final triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(195): Allocated 60400 bytes (58 KiB) for single-phone word triphones
INFO: ngram_model_arpa.c(77): No \data\ mark in LM file
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(142): Will use memory-mapped I/O for LM file
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(196): ngrams 1=5001, 2=436879, 3=418286
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(242):     5001 = LM.unigrams(+trailer) read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(288):   436879 = LM.bigrams(+trailer) read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(314):   418286 = LM.trigrams read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(339):    37293 = LM.prob2 entries read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(359):    14370 = LM.bo_wt2 entries read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(379):    36094 = LM.prob3 entries read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(407):      854 = LM.tseg_base entries read
INFO: ngram_model_dmp.c(463):     5001 = ascii word strings read
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(99): 788 unique initial diphones
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(147): 0 root, 0 non-root channels, 60 single-phone words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(186): Creating search tree
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(191): before: 0 root, 0 non-root channels, 60 single-phone words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(326): after: max nonroot chan increased to 13428
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(338): after: 457 root, 13300 non-root channels, 26 single-phone words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(156): fwdflat: min_ef_width = 4, max_sf_win = 25
INFO: continuous.c(371): pocketsphinx_continuous COMPILED ON: Dec 22 2013, AT: 20:43:21
```

Then I ran livedemo.py from `pocketsphinx/src/gst-plugin` This is the error I get:

```
thekindlyone@deepthought:~/.../gst-plugin$ python livedemo.py
Using pygtkcompat and Gst from gi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "livedemo.py", line 102, in <module>
    app = DemoApp()
  File "livedemo.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.init_gst()
  File "livedemo.py", line 53, in init_gst
    + '! pocketsphinx configured=true ! fakesink')
gi._glib.GError: no element "pocketsphinx"
thekindlyone@deepthought:~/.../gst-plugin$
```

I found that I have export a new path as per [cmusphinx wiki](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/gstreamer). But `/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0` is not present. What should I do next?

output of `gst-inspect-1.0 pocketsphinx`

```
No such element or plugin 'pocketsphinx'
```

output of `gst-inspect pocketsphinx`

```
Factory Details:
  Long name:    PocketSphinx
  Class:    Filter/Audio
  Description:  Convert speech to text
  Author(s):    David Huggins-Daines <dhuggins@cs.cmu.edu>
  Rank:     none (0)

Plugin Details:
  Name:         pocketsphinx
  Description:      PocketSphinx plugin
  Filename:     /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstpocketsphinx.so
  Version:      0.8
  License:      BSD
  Source module:    pocketsphinx
  Binary package:   PocketSphinx
  Origin URL:       http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

GObject
 +----GstObject
       +----GstElement
             +----GstPocketSphinx

Pad Templates:
  SINK template: 'sink'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      audio/x-raw-int
                  width: 16
                  depth: 16
                 signed: true
             endianness: 1234
               channels: 1
                   rate: 8000

  SRC template: 'src'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      text/plain


Element Flags:
  no flags set

Element Implementation:
  Has change_state() function: gst_element_change_state_func
  Has custom save_thyself() function: gst_element_save_thyself
  Has custom restore_thyself() function: gst_element_restore_thyself

Element has no clocking capabilities.
Element has no indexing capabilities.
Element has no URI handling capabilities.

Pads:
  SRC: 'src'
    Implementation:
      Has custom eventfunc(): gst_pad_event_default
      Has custom queryfunc(): gst_pad_query_default
      Has custom iterintlinkfunc(): gst_pad_iterate_internal_links_default
      Has getcapsfunc(): gst_pad_get_fixed_caps_func
      Has acceptcapsfunc(): gst_pad_acceptcaps_default
    Pad Template: 'src'
  SINK: 'sink'
    Implementation:
      Has chainfunc(): 0x7f4e0c00c4f0
      Has custom eventfunc(): 0x7f4e0c00c1b0
      Has custom queryfunc(): gst_pad_query_default
      Has custom iterintlinkfunc(): gst_pad_iterate_internal_links_default
      Has getcapsfunc(): gst_pad_get_fixed_caps_func
      Has acceptcapsfunc(): gst_pad_acceptcaps_default
    Pad Template: 'sink'

Element Properties:
  name                : The name of the object
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: "pocketsphinx0"
  hmm                 : Directory containing acoustic model parameters
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: null
  lm                  : Language model file
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: null
  lmctl               : Language model control file (for class LMs)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: null
  lmname              : Language model name (to select LMs from lmctl)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: "default"
  dict                : Dictionary File
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: null
  mllr                : MLLR file
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: null
  fsg                 : Finite state grammar file
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: null
  fsg-model           : Finite state grammar object (fsg_model_t *)
                        flags: writable
                        Pointer. Write only
  fwdflat             : Enable Flat Lexicon Search
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: false
  bestpath            : Enable Graph Search
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: false
  maxhmmpf            : Maximum number of HMMs searched per frame
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer. Range: 1 - 100000 Default: 2000 
  maxwpf              : Maximum number of words searched per frame
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer. Range: 1 - 100000 Default: 20 
  beam                : Beam width applied to every frame in Viterbi search
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Float. Range:              -1 -               1 Default:               0 
  wbeam               : Beam width applied to phone transitions
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Float. Range:              -1 -               1 Default:               0 
  pbeam               : Beam width applied to phone transitions
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Float. Range:              -1 -               1 Default:               0 
  dsratio             : Evaluate acoustic model every N frames
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer. Range: 1 - 10 Default: 1 
  latdir              : Output Directory for Lattices
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: null
  lattice             : Word lattice object for most recent result
                        flags: readable
                        Boxed pointer of type "PSLattice"
  nbest               : N-best results
                        flags: readable
                        Array of GValues of type "gchararray"
  nbest-size          : Number of hypothesis in the N-best list
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer. Range: 1 - 1000 Default: 10 
  decoder             : The underlying decoder
                        flags: readable
                        Boxed pointer of type "PSDecoder"
  configured          : Set this to finalize configuration
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: false

Element Signals:
  "partial-result" :  void user_function (GstElement* object,
                                          gchararray arg0,
                                          gchararray arg1,
                                          gpointer user_data);
  "result" :  void user_function (GstElement* object,
                                  gchararray arg0,
                                  gchararray arg1,
                                  gpointer user_data);
```

---

**UPDATES**:

I downloaded fresh copies from github and installed, no change.
[sphinxbase build](http://pastebin.com/AZHC4t6h)

[sphinxbase install](http://pastebin.com/G9nFieDJ)

[pocketsphinx build](http://pastebin.com/R4h799cj)

[pocketsphinx install](http://pastebin.com/8dAPppTz)

Comment: You installed old version of pocketsphinx, you need to install latest pocketsphinx and sphinxbase from github.

Comment: I installed fresh copies from github. same thing, pocketsphinx_continuous works. But now `gst-inspect pocketsphinx` also returns "no such element or plugin 'pocketsphinx' "

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev  according to your comment here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28767065/1248662 lack of /usr/local/lib/gstreamer* implies the plugins were not compiled. Is this my problem as well? If yes, how do I fix?

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev here is my config.log from pocketsphinx http://pastebin.com/kr4QaeNL and same for sphinxbase http://pastebin.com/1ZysCYCN

Comment: From the config log everything is fine. You need to provide build and installation log. To make sure gstreamer finds new plugins you need to set GST_PLUGIN_PATH

Comment: sphinxbase build : http://pastebin.com/AZHC4t6h
sphinxbase install : http://pastebin.com/G9nFieDJ
pocketsphinx build : http://pastebin.com/R4h799cj
pocketsphinx install : http://pastebin.com/8dAPppTz

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev oh this time /usr/local/lib/gstreamer1.0 is created. Works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

5th attempt on clean install worked. /usr/local/lib/gstreamer1.0 created. Adding this to GST_PLUGIN_PATH worked.